# Linux server file upload

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I can't upload files. The detailed error message is shown below.

I've tried changing maxUploadsize -1 but I am getting the same error.

I have also checked Maxupload size -1 in spring configuration file as it shown below, but it was not successful either.

Has anyone seen this error or know the cause?

---

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" /> <!-- 20MB -->

  <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
  <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="129059638" /> <!-- 1MB -->

</bean>
```

---

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/AutoBCM_Alpha_v2/upload_2f8777c9_170d42a1309__8000_00000055.tmp
>   (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native
>   Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138) at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:719)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) at
>   java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1412) at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) at
>   com.ascent.bcm.applayer.Applayer.receiveData(Applayer.java:239) at
>   com.ascent.bcm.applayer.Applayer.validateUser(Applayer.java:267) at
>   com.ascent.bcm.applayer.BcmBIAAppController.slaDocFileUpload(BcmBIAAppController.java:4593)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: edited content for legibility

Answer (score 0):

Why do you suspect that maxFileUploadSize is the culprit?

The error message is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/AutoBCM_Alpha_v2/upload_2f8777c9_170d42a1309__8000_00000055.tmp (No such file or directory)
```

Without more of your file-upload code, it will be hard to tell what is really going wrong, apart from that "a" file or directory is missing.